# How to step into a dll method call or constructor so that it will ask for the source?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a common dll that I am using for my project.  We have made it a nuget package and use it locally in my company.

However, now I am getting a null reference exception from inside that dll.  If I try to step into it (F11) it just steps over it.

Now, I come from a Delphi background, and in Delphi, you could provide the code for a library and it would let you step through it.

I am hoping that there is a way to say, "here is the code, please step through it as if were the dll I am using."

Otherwise I am going to have to go and change the references to this dll and then add the code to the project.  I can do that, but it seems like there should be an easier way.

Comment: If you have kept the symbol files, you should be able to step through. It depends on how your assemblies are built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your dll is also of debug build and the .pdb file generated with the dll is placed in the same location as the dll. Rebuild your current project and you should be able to step into the function calls.

Comment: That was it.  Once I copied in a Debug dll and the .pdb it worked great!

Answer (score 5):

Try this

Go to Debug->Options and Setting->Debugging -> General -> Uncheck Option : Enable Just My Code and then try to step in using F11

Another thing you can try is to manually load the symbols of other dll. Once you are in debug mode (before stepping into the other dll code) go to Debug->Windows->Modules. It will show you all the loaded dlls. Right click on your dll and manually load symbols for it

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source code in another proyect, try to execute your aplicacion and attach to it (in VS menu Debug -> Attach to Process). Yoy should be able to debug inside the DLL.

Other option would be to use .NET Reflector or ILSpy. They allow you to debug inside a DLL if it has not been ofuscated.